# Lenovo G550 - Intel GMA4500 slowness on 12.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

My machine is **Lenovo G550** with **Intel GMA4500** and clean install of **Ubuntu 12.04**

Every new version of Ubuntu and maby sometimes when I have time I came to Ubuntu and give it a try. But every time I meet with problems. When I'd installed Ubuntu, I feel that everything is slow and a little bit sluggish.

---

My friend have tried me help and told me, that I shoud try this things:

```
$ glxinfo | grep direct
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

Results:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:

$ glxinfo | grep direct
direct rendering: Yes
```

And with: `glxgears` I got 60fps thanks to vsync no more for sure... So hw acceleration seems to be working, but I am not 100% sure about it.

---

But on the other side, maby I am spoiled with Windows 8... I don't think so. Opening nautilus for the first time is slow, Unity Dash last 2sec to open. Opening Chrome and FF is slow too and using it too.

---

I really want to use Ubuntu for my daily use and helps it to improve and maby later write some program for its. I think, that Ubuntu has a big potential, but these things make me crazy. Could someone help me, please? =) What I have to do, to make it smooth?

PS: Unity2D works like that...

Comment: Did you install ubuntu 12.04? Is it installed in a separate disk partition or installed in windows(through wubi)? Try Lubuntu: http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: Yes I did and in a separate disk partition next to Windows. Lubuntu isn't solution. I want to use Ubuntu as other milions of people and I like Unity.

Comment: Please, paste the output of the `lscpu` command, and tell us also your CPU's frequence. Ubuntu has a "energy saver" or something which reduces the frequence of the CPU (in my 2000MHz CPU, it saw a 800MHz CPU). Perhaps tweaking it to reach the real frequence may help.

Comment: lscpu shows 2300Mhz when I open any program and 1200Mhz in peace @AddisonMontgomery